# Add additional product information on Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product

In WooCommerce, I have a custom product field **"Time"** for which I want to output the field's value on checkout, specifically in the product details, under product name, to have it like this: `Event time: (value from wcv_custom_product_field)`

I've tried placing :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_checkout_producttime', 10, 2 );

function wc_checkout_producttime( $other_data, $cart_item )
{
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];

    $other_data[] = array( 'name' =>  'wcv_custom_product_field', 'value' => $_product->get_wcv_custom_product_field() );
return $other_data;
}
```

But I'm getting ablank page on the checkout.

What I am doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_get_item_data`** filter hook that will display your product custom field in cart and checkout items:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_product_field_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {

    // Define HERE your product custom field meta key  <==   <==   <==   <==   <==
    $meta_key = 'wcv_custom_product_field';

    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, $meta_key, true );

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
        $custom_items = $cart_data;

    if( !empty($meta_value) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Event time', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => $meta_value,
            'display'   => $meta_value,
        );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.